# How to pull additional results from a SQL select query

Tags: sql, select

I have a select query that combines an order table and a delivery address table to give orders sent by postcode area for a given date range as follows:

```
    SELECT CASE
    WHEN ISNUMERIC(RIGHT(LEFT(addrPostcode, 2), 1)) = '0' THEN LEFT(addrPostcode, 2)
    ELSE LEFT(addrPostcode, 1)
    END AS 'PostcodeArea', COUNT(addrPostcode) AS 'Orders Sent To Postcode Area'
    FROM Addresses INNER JOIN Orders ON Addresses.addrID = Orders.deliveryAddrID
    WHERE orderDate BETWEEN '2022-07-01' AND '2022-08-01'
    GROUP BY CASE
    WHEN ISNUMERIC(RIGHT(LEFT(addrPostcode, 2), 1)) = '0' THEN LEFT(addrPostcode, 2)
    ELSE LEFT(addrPostcode, 1)
    END
    ORDER BY 'Orders Sent To Postcode Area' DESC
```

I would like to combine the results of the query to include the population of the postcode area that is stored in a third table with:

```
    SELECT Population
    FROM PostcodeData
    WHERE PostcodeArea = 'PostcodeArea'
```

This will allow me to see if order volumes sent to an area are relative to it's population density. But how are the 2 queries combined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to add a subquery expression:

```
SELECT
    PostCodeArea,
    [Orders Sent To Postcode Area],
    (SELECT Population
     FROM PostcodeData PDat
     WHERE PDat.PostcodeArea = s1.PostCodeArea) AS PostCodeAreaPopulation
FROM (
    SELECT 
       CASE
          WHEN ISNUMERIC(RIGHT(LEFT(addrPostcode, 2), 1)) = 0 
                     THEN LEFT(addrPostcode, 2)
          ELSE LEFT(addrPostcode, 1)
       END AS PostcodeArea
     , COUNT(addrPostcode) AS [Orders Sent To Postcode Area]
    FROM 
        Addresses 
        INNER JOIN Orders 
        ON Addresses.addrID = Orders.deliveryAddrID
    WHERE orderDate BETWEEN '2022-07-01' AND '2022-08-01'
    GROUP BY 
      CASE
        WHEN ISNUMERIC(RIGHT(LEFT(addrPostcode, 2), 1)) = 0 THEN LEFT(addrPostcode, 2)
        ELSE LEFT(addrPostcode, 1)
      END
) S1
ORDER BY [Orders Sent To Postcode Area] DESC
```

To avoid adding the whole subquery to GROUP BY, I added it at a higher level.
Make sure that the subquery return only one row (ie PostCodeArea is unique in PostCodeData.

Or join it:

````
``` -lang-sql
SELECT 
   CASE
      WHEN ISNUMERIC(RIGHT(LEFT(addrPostcode, 2), 1)) = 0 
                 THEN LEFT(addrPostcode, 2)
      ELSE LEFT(addrPostcode, 1)
   END AS PostcodeArea
 , PDat.Population
 , COUNT(addrPostcode) AS [Orders Sent To Postcode Area]
FROM 
    Addresses 
    INNER JOIN Orders 
    ON Addresses.addrID = Orders.deliveryAddrID
    
    LEFT JOIN PostcodeData PDat
    ON PDat.PostcodeArea = CASE
                            WHEN ISNUMERIC(RIGHT(LEFT(addrPostcode, 2), 1)) = 0 
                            THEN LEFT(addrPostcode, 2)
                            ELSE LEFT(addrPostcode, 1)
                            END
 
WHERE orderDate BETWEEN '2022-07-01' AND '2022-08-01'
GROUP BY 
  CASE
    WHEN ISNUMERIC(RIGHT(LEFT(addrPostcode, 2), 1)) = 0 THEN LEFT(addrPostcode, 2)
    ELSE LEFT(addrPostcode, 1)
  END,
  PDat.Population
ORDER BY [Orders Sent To Postcode Area] DESC
````

You can change the LEFT JOIN to INNER JOIN if it is guaranteed that you will find tows in PostCodeData

Comment: So, the first option returns NULL for all the PostCodeAreaPopulation and the second option throws the following error: Column 'PCAPop.Population' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: if it produces null, it means that 'SELECT Population
    FROM PostcodeData
    WHERE PostcodeArea = 'PostcodeArea' produces null  (or returns no rows); run the subquery separately and only use it if it returns something. You gave us that query.

Comment: When I run the subquery separately substituting 'PostcodeArea' with 'BT' (which is Northern Ireland) a correct result is returned.

Comment: Using the second part of your answer works perfectly. Thank you very much for taking the time to solve the problem. By reading through the solution I can now understand the logic.